# Python Pandas apply a function on non empty cells

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function on non empty cells of a column that contains either integer numbers or empty cells. I checked the data type of that column, it is object.

This is part of the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Seam_Height': {0: 72.0, 1: 108.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 84.0, 5: 96.0,
                     6: nan, 7: 108.0, 8: 120.0, 9: nan, 10: 120.0, 11: nan,
                     12: 120.0, 13: 107.0},
     'mining_method': {0: 'Longwall', 1: 'Longwall', 2: 'Longwall',
                       3: 'Longwall', 4: 'Longwall', 5: 'Longwall',
                       6: 'Longwall', 7: 'Longwall', 8: 'Longwall',
                       9: 'Longwall', 10: 'Longwall', 11: 'Longwall',
                       12: 'Longwall', 13: 'Longwall'},
     'employee_num ': {0: 508.0, 1: 161.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 547.0, 5: 354.0,
                       6: 456.0, 7: nan, 8: 515.0, 9: 515.0, 10: nan, 11: 515.0,
                       12: 515.0, 13: 235.0}}
)

    Seam_Height mining_method  employee_num 
0          72.0      Longwall          508.0
1         108.0      Longwall          161.0
2           NaN      Longwall            NaN
3           NaN      Longwall            NaN
4          84.0      Longwall          547.0
5          96.0      Longwall          354.0
6           NaN      Longwall          456.0
7         108.0      Longwall            NaN
8         120.0      Longwall          515.0
9           NaN      Longwall          515.0
10        120.0      Longwall            NaN
11          NaN      Longwall          515.0
12        120.0      Longwall          515.0
13        107.0      Longwall          235.0
```

This is the function that I used to classify the thickness of seam height, it is a very simple function:

```
def seam_thickness_class_func(var):
     if var < 43:
         return "V_low"
     if var < 60:
        return "Low"
    if var < 72:
         return "Medium"
    else:
          return "High"



df['Seam_class'] = df.apply(lambda x: seam_thickness_class_func(x["Seam_Height"]) if(pd.notnull(x[0])) else " ", axis = 1)
```

The function will be applied if the cell contains a number, while if it is empty, it retruns " ".

I get this error message when I apply the function:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: This seems to imply that Seam_Height is a string rather than a number. Can you provide a reproducible sample of your dataframe rather than an image? The output from `print(df.to_dict())` for example.

Comment: {'Seam_Height': {0: 72.0, 1: 108.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 84.0, 5: 96.0, 6: nan, 7: 108.0, 8: 120.0, 9: nan, 10: 120.0, 11: nan, 12: 120.0, 13: 107.0}, 'mining_method': {0: 'Longwall', 1: 'Longwall', 2: 'Longwall', 3: 'Longwall', 4: 'Longwall', 5: 'Longwall', 6: 'Longwall', 7: 'Longwall', 8: 'Longwall', 9: 'Longwall', 10: 'Longwall', 11: 'Longwall', 12: 'Longwall', 13: 'Longwall'}, 'employee_num ': {0: 508.0, 1: 161.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 547.0, 5: 354.0, 6: 456.0, 7: nan, 8: 515.0, 9: 515.0, 10: nan, 11: 515.0, 12: 515.0, 13: 235.0}}

Comment: Thank you. I've [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69869383/edit) your question to include the information where it is more accessible. Next question You appear to call the function `thickness_group_func` but the function you've provided is `seam_thickness_class_func` is this  a typo? Or have you included the wrong function?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question, it is a typo. I used the right function name.

Comment: I corrected the function name in the post. Thanks for catching my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) then [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) instead. [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) is specifically designed to:

> Bin values into discrete intervals.

We can bin the values:

1. (-∞, 43) with label V_low
2. [43, 60) with Low
3. [60, 72) with Medium
4. [72, ∞) with High

Note `right=False` means upper bound non-inclusive. Which is analogous of strictly less than in the shown function.

```
# import numpy as np
df['Seam_class'] = pd.cut(
    pd.to_numeric(df['Seam_Height'], errors='coerce'),
    bins=[np.NINF, 43, 60, 72, np.inf],
    labels=['V_low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
    right=False
)
```

`df`:

```
   Seam_Height mining_method  employee_num  Seam_class
0         72.0      Longwall          508.0       High
1        108.0      Longwall          161.0       High
2                   Longwall            NaN        NaN
3          NaN      Longwall            NaN        NaN
4         84.0      Longwall          547.0       High
5         96.0      Longwall          354.0       High
6          NaN      Longwall          456.0        NaN
7        108.0      Longwall            NaN       High
8        120.0      Longwall          515.0       High
9          NaN      Longwall          515.0        NaN
10       120.0      Longwall            NaN       High
11         NaN      Longwall          515.0        NaN
12       120.0      Longwall          515.0       High
13       107.0      Longwall          235.0       High
```

We can further [`add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for missing values to be replaced with `' '`:

```
# import numpy as np
df['Seam_class'] = pd.cut(
    pd.to_numeric(df['Seam_Height'], errors='coerce'),
    bins=[np.NINF, 43, 60, 72, np.inf],
    labels=['V_low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
    right=False
).cat.add_categories(' ').fillna(' ')
```

`df`:

```
    Seam_Height mining_method  employee_num  Seam_class
0          72.0      Longwall          508.0       High
1         108.0      Longwall          161.0       High
2           NaN      Longwall            NaN           
3           NaN      Longwall            NaN           
4          84.0      Longwall          547.0       High
5          96.0      Longwall          354.0       High
6           NaN      Longwall          456.0           
7         108.0      Longwall            NaN       High
8         120.0      Longwall          515.0       High
9           NaN      Longwall          515.0           
10        120.0      Longwall            NaN       High
11          NaN      Longwall          515.0           
12        120.0      Longwall          515.0       High
13        107.0      Longwall          235.0       High
```

---

If we need to fix the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) version, we should use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) instead after converting the column [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to ensure we're only dealing with numeric values, and address the null checking in the function itself:

```
def seam_thickness_class_func(var):
    # Test isnull here
    if pd.isnull(var):
        return ' '
    if var < 43:
        return "V_low"
    if var < 60:
        return "Low"
    if var < 72:
        return "Medium"
    return "High"


df['Seam_class'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['Seam_Height'], errors='coerce'
).apply(seam_thickness_class_func)
```

`df`:

```
    Seam_Height mining_method  employee_num  Seam_class
0          72.0      Longwall          508.0       High
1         108.0      Longwall          161.0       High
2           NaN      Longwall            NaN           
3           NaN      Longwall            NaN           
4          84.0      Longwall          547.0       High
5          96.0      Longwall          354.0       High
6           NaN      Longwall          456.0           
7         108.0      Longwall            NaN       High
8         120.0      Longwall          515.0       High
9           NaN      Longwall          515.0           
10        120.0      Longwall            NaN       High
11          NaN      Longwall          515.0           
12        120.0      Longwall          515.0       High
13        107.0      Longwall          235.0       High
```